# port listening on wrong network interface

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008, msmq

I have Hamachi installed on a server (aws-ec2 machine) and I'm trying to open a port on the machine for msmq.

I used the following command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="open port 1801" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1801
```

I also allowed incoming TCP connections to 1801 in the AWS security groups.

My problem is when I run the command `netstat -ao` to see what ports are listening, I only see the port listening on the IP address Hamachi has assigned to the computer.  But it is not listening on the local private IP address (10.x.x.x).

Anybody have any idea how to get it to listen on the local IP?  Been Googling forever with no success for an answer.

Thanks to all who can give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that it is not binding to the correct interface.  You will likely have to change the binding order of the adapters such that the adapter with the local IP is preferred.

Instructions are here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894564